# binomial distribution/exact/approximate results

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Of 1000 roses, on average 20% are damaged, a seller sells 10 roses with which probability will at most 1 rose be damaged?

So for the approximate solution we use the same damage probability for the 10 roses as for the whole bag of 1000 roses, which
would be B(10, 0.2, 0)+B(10,0.2,1)=0.3758

for the exact solution it is given p=0.3746

and I wanted to ask whether someone could tell me how the exact solution could be calculated?

Comment: In much the same way as the binomial approximation is obtained. Assume there are $200$ damaged roses and $800$ intact roses.  The probability that the first is damaged and none of the others are is $\frac {200}{1000}\times \frac {800}{999}\times \frac {799}{998}\times \cdots\times \frac {792}{991}=0.026843088$ Now multiply by $10$ and add in the case where all $10$ are good.

Comment: @lulu, thank you! I did that and got the result, I wanted to ask is there an analytical formula for that? to calculate it more quickly? for example if the smaller bag size was not 10, but 50?

Comment: Well, you are talking about ratios of factorials, and there are a lot of good analytic approximations for factorials.  In practice, though, I expect it takes too long to sort out which approximations are valid in any given situation.  Since, no doubt, one is automating the thing, I'd just do it exactly unless the numbers were huge.

Comment: Exact hypergeometric in R where `phyper` is hypergeometric CDF, etc.: code `phyper(1, 200,800, 10)` returns $0.3745953;$ approx. binomial, often OK if less than 10% of population sampled: `pbinom(1, 10, .2)` returns $0.3758096;$ misguided Poisson aprx. to binom., assuming rate of damage per 10 roses is $\lambda = 2$: `ppois(1, 2)` returns $0.4060058;$ misguided normal aprx to binom with $\mu = 10(.2), \sigma=\sqrt{10(.2)(.8)},$ and using continuity correction: `pnorm(1.5, mu, sg)` returns $0.3463164.$  Could also use normal aprx with hyperg SD, but that'd not be much better $(n$ too small).

Comment: Hypergeometric: $\frac{ {200\choose 0}{800\choose 10}}{{1000\choose 10}}$ +$\frac{{200\choose 1}{800\choose 9}}{{1000\choose 10}}.$

Comment: `a = choose(800,10)/choose(1000,10);                `
`b = 200*choose(800,9)/choose(1000,10);               `
`a+b                                             ` `[1] 0.3745953`

Comment: @BruceET thank you so much for the detailed explanation